# Violin plots don't show expected density curves as expected when unique points are less than four

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, violin-plot

## Background

I am playing box plots and violin plots with `ggplot2`, but I find some odd phenomena which happen only when the number of unique data are less than four. I am not very sure whether SO is the proper place for this thread, if not, please guild me to the right place.

## Single data point: plot is not rendered

```
df <- data.frame(state = "bedtime", value = 100)
```

### Box plot

```
ggplot(aes(x = state, y = value), data = df) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

[image]

### Violin plot

```
ggplot(aes(x = state, y = value), data = df) + geom_violin()
```

Nothing. Received a warning message.

[image]

## Two to three data points: plot is sometimes rendered

If it's not, it's like the case of single data point. If it's rendered, the quantile lines are inconsistent.

```
df <- data.frame(state = rep("after_meal", 4), value = rep(c(178, 162), each = 2))
```

### Box plot

```
ggplot(aes(x = state, y = value), data = df) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

[image]

### Violin plot

```
ggplot(aes(x = state, y = value), data = df) + geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

[image]

As you can see, the quantile lines are inconsistent with each other.

## Questions

1. Why isn't the violin plot showed when there's only one data point? I looked up [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), and I thought there should be a very wide but flat violin. Are there other limitations or constraint in [`geom_violin`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html)? Or is it the rule of violin plots?
2. Why are the 25% and 75% quantiles put at different places between a box plot and a violin plot in the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A violin plot is a density **estimate** plot reflected along the vertical axis, and is different from a box plot in that a box plot shows the data itself.

So as to your first question, with one point the density is infinite, because you request it at one specific point in space with a zero width, i.e. infinite height (to see this, replace `geom_violin` with `geom_density`.

The second issue stems from the same thing: a box plot is more accurate for a small number of points, because a density estimation is continuous, and is not well-defined for a very short range.